# Spontaneous CSS Problems

Tags: css

I was working on the print CSS for a webpage of mine, and for some impossible reason, my website's CSS (as presented to a computer screen) became very odd. Firebug says that a user agent stylesheet is causing portions of my page to have enormous margins in random places for no reason. I have no idea how this could have possibly been caused.

Anyway, to begin, how can I get rid of user agent stylesheets?

Comment: The only way to "get rid of" a user agent stylesheet is to override it with your own CSS. Can you post some code for us to review so we can see the problem for ourselves?

Comment: I don't think your question makes much sense. CSS doesn't just randomly/spontaneously decide to add "enormous margins" for no reason. Maybe including a screenshot of Firebug, showing the "enormous margins" would help.

Answer (score 5):

Try using a [reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) sheet. This will reset all browsers to have the same styles to begin with, and should fix it.

Comment: I found the problem - I had deleted a minor CSS file that was outdated but happened to contain reset code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Already tried to empty your cache?

Ctrl + F5 works wonders sometimes